# on nested CES--derivation issue

Tags: macroeconomics, ces-function, ces

I am reading Sachs and Kotlikoff (2012 NBER) and am wondering how they derive one equation in their paper. The setting is the following:

---

Their model is a variant of the standard two-period overlapping generation (OLG) model. The production function includes three inputs: machines $M$, unskilled labor $L$, and skilled labor $S$. Gross output $Q$ is a constant elasticity of substitution (CES) production function of stocks $M, L,$ and $S$:

(1) $Q=Q[N(u M, L), S],$

where $M$ and $L$ are combined in a CES production function with elasticity $\varepsilon M L$ to generate an intermediate output $N$, and $N$ and $S$ are combined in a CES production function with elasticity $\varepsilon S N$ to produce the final output $Q$. (I believe $\varepsilon M L$ is a constant independent of $M$ and $L$, and they meant to write it like $\varepsilon_{ M L}$).  $u$ is a parameter measuring the technical efficiency of machinery.

$M, L$, and $S$ are determined by past investments and are fully employed. Competitive firms purchase $M, L$, and $S$ until their marginal products (denoted as $Q_{i}$ for $i=M, L$, and $S$ ) equal their market wages:

(2) $\mathrm{Q}_{\mathrm{i}}=\mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{i}}$

Consider the effect of a rise on $\mathrm{u}$ on the wage of unskilled workers, $\mathrm{Q}_{\mathrm{L}}=\mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{L}}$. In particular,  $\operatorname{dln}\left(Q_{L}\right) / d \ln (u)$. They claim that a bit of algebra leads to:

$
(3) \operatorname{dln}\left(Q_{L}\right) / d \ln (u)=[\varepsilon S N-\theta \varepsilon M L] / \varepsilon M L
$

where $\theta$ is the share of skilled labor in the economy, equal to $\left(Q_{s} * S\right) / Q$.

---

I tried to derive equation (3), but embarrassingly, I was not able to. **Can anyone help me derive (3) step by step?** Thank you in advance!